# Best way to visualize graph on a text console?

Tags: charts, console, data-validation

I looking for a solution to visualize a graph on a standard unix text console. Speaking more precisely I need to visualize a graph of dependencies between files from specified set, those dependencies are represented as directed acyclic graph.

Comment: Thats a tall order for a standard text console.  especially if you need to limit terminal emulation in any way, e.g. vt100 80 column.

Answer (score 2):

I believe GnuPlot can do this

There are also Perl modules that do this sort of thing:

```
        use Graph::Easy;

        my $graph = Graph::Easy->new();

        $graph->add_edge_once ('Bonn', 'Berlin');

        print $graph->as_ascii( );

        # prints:

        # +------+     +--------+
        # | Bonn | --> | Berlin |
        # +------+     +--------+
```